# Sum of infinite series with limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having trouble determining whether 
$\frac{2n^2+n-3}{5n^2-1}$ is diverging or converging and finding the $\sum_1^\infty$ of the equation.

I think I'm correct in saying it converges to the limit is $\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: Do you mean the sequence or the series ? If you mean the sequence, then yes, the limit is actually $\frac{2}{5}$. Therefore, the series cannot converge because the limit would have to be $0$.

Comment: Series, all the values added i believe

Comment: @Aristotle $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2n^2+n-3}{5n^2-1}\ge \frac{2(N-2)}{5}\to \infty$ as $N\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n^2+n-3}{5n^2-1}=\frac{2}{5}$$

the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n^2+n-3}{5n^2-1}$$ diverges because the limit is $\ne 0$ and for sufficient large $n$, the summands are positive.

Comment: Thankyou so sum is non existent?

Comment: @Aristotle yes, the sum diverges to $\infty$